# RTL8192CE Wifi driver Issue

Tags: wireless, drivers

Everyone ,
                 I am using Ubuntu10.10. My Laptop is Lenovo Model T420. I am not able to install it's WIFI driver.Please tell me how can i install it's Wifi driver.

Comment: Unable why? What's wrong? Do you get any errors when installing? Does your finger gets stuck or the monitor goes blank?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 2):

The rtl8192ce driver is included in the kernel, what probably is missing is the firmware. Install package `linux-firmware-nonfree`.